# Why can't I insert yyyymmdd (stored as text) to a date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, type-conversion

This has been asked many times before and I tried quite a bit before posting this question. I have 2 columns on my SQL Server table where the dates are stored as CHAR(8) yyyymmdd format. When I try to insert this to another table with date column, I get:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

The typecasting that I used is:

```
    ,CAST(convert(char(10),qrda.BillFromDate,120) AS DATE) AS [BillStartDate]
    ,CAST(convert(char(10),qrda.BillToDate,120) AS DATE) AS [BillEndDate]
```

With the above code, I am trying to make it SQL Server readable date format and then typecasting it to DATE so that I can insert it to the destination table without any other transformations. Not sure where I am going wrong with this.

Comment: Why not just [directly cast it](https://rextester.com/WVS22570): `CAST(qrda.BillFromDate AS DATE)`

Comment: you are giving it style 120 -- that looks like this "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss (24h)" -- not what your data looks like.

Comment: That data is style 112, and is also should work with an implicit conversion.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Just going to leave this here...https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since date are stored in the following format `yyyyMMdd` you can insert these values without any need to use `CONVERT` or `CAST` functions, since this format can be implicitly converted to DATE.

If the data contains invalid values such as `00000000`, you can use `TRY_CONVERT` or `TRY_PARSE` function to convert these values to `NULL`

*Example:*

```sql
CREATE TABLE #TBLTEMP(datecolumn DATETIME)


INSERT INTO #TBLTEMP(datecolumn)
VALUES ('20180101')

INSERT INTO #TBLTEMP(datecolumn)
VALUES (TRY_PARSE('00000000' as DATETIME))


SELECT * FROM #TBLTEMP
```

*Result:*

[image]

From the example above, you can see that `20180101` was inserted succesfly without any casting, while `TRY_PARSE` function converted the invalid value `00000000` to `NULL`.

You can use the following syntax:

```sql
INSERT INTO TargetTable(DateColumn)
SELECT TRY_PARSE([CharColumn] as DATETIME
FROM SourceTable
```

---

#### References

- [Understanding SQL Server’s TRY_PARSE and TRY_CONVERT functions](https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-sql-servers-try_parse-and-try_convert-functions/)
- [TRY_PARSE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I am going to mark this as an answer because these seem to perfectly fit the bad data situation. Thanks1

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the trouble folks, but looks like this is bad production data where some values are literally '00000000'. I dont know how this flows into our system, but since the source table columns are CHAR(8), this is a valid value. Not so much for me.

Comment: Yikes. That is further evidence that choosing the correct datatype for what you are storing is extremely important. Any chance you can fix the table and store dates as dates instead of strings?

Comment: I will take this up with the owners of the data, but I currently dont control how it gets loaded. If I would've developed this originally, I would've not chosen such poor practices.

Comment: I feel your pain there. We often get handed things based on poor decisions made by other people and have to deal with the fallout. from your current situation the TRY_PARSE from Hadi is about the best option you have.